# ActiveRecord in Rails 5.2: save/update does not save record, even if it says it does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5.2.4.1 app in production with ruby 2.6.5, postgres 10.11 and pg gem version 1.1.4, I have an ActiveRecord model like this:

```rb
class RealEstate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :developer, optional: true
  belongs_to :customer, optional: true
  # Do not fetch heavy/noisy columns such as JSONB metadata
  scope :light, -> { select(RealEstate.column_names.map!(&:to_sym) - [:metadata]) }
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
  has_many :lots, -> { where(lot: true) }, class_name: 'RealEstate', foreign_key: 'program_id'
  belongs_to :program, class_name: 'RealEstate', optional: true

  enum old_or_new: {
    old: 0,
    new_building: 1 # developers new real estate programs
  }

  enum transaction_type: {
    rent: 0,
    buy: 1
  }

  enum property_category: {
    apartment: 0,
    house: 1,
    other: 2
  }
end
```

The underlying data model, in `db/structure.sql` is like this (some columns anonymized):

```
CREATE TABLE public.real_estates (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    geom public.geometry(Point),
    title character varying,
    description text,
    address character varying,
    old_or_new integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    property_category integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    some_string character varying,
    some_string_2 text,
    price integer,
    created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    some_string_3 character varying,
    metadata jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL,
    some_string_4 character varying,
    active boolean DEFAULT true NOT NULL,
    customer_id bigint,
    some_string_5 character varying,
    transaction_type integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    some_string_6 character varying,
    some_boolean_1 boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    country_code character varying(2) DEFAULT 'FR'::character varying,
    some_boolean_2 boolean DEFAULT true NOT NULL,
    some_timestamp_1 timestamp without time zone,
    some_timestamp_2 timestamp without time zone,
    some_array integer[] DEFAULT '{}'::integer[],
    some_string_7 character varying,
    some_count integer,
    some_other_integer integer,
    some_boolean_3 boolean DEFAULT true NOT NULL,
    some_string_8 character varying,
    some_timestamp_3 timestamp without time zone,
    some_boolean_4 boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    program_id bigint,
    some_string_9 character varying,
    developer_id bigint,
    some_boolean_4 boolean DEFAULT false,
    some_boolean_5 boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT countrycode CHECK (((country_code)::text ~* '[A-Z][A-Z]'::text))
);
```

Like you can see, there are no Rails callbacks. The "oddities" - we use a postgres JSONB column and a postgres integer array column.

Now we have an admin update route to edit some of those records. It's not following naming conventions, and not using active record validations but `dry-validations`:

```
require 'dry-validation'

module Admin
  class NewRealEstatesController < Admin::BaseController
    before_action :set_form, only: [:edit, :update]

    def update
      validation_result = AdminRealEstateSchema.call(real_estate_listing_params.to_h)
      if validation_result.success?
        # Don't mind column mappings with the dry schema validator, there might be inconsistencies
       # because I anonymized the column names, but the mapping is correct and validations pass
        @estate.some_string_1 =  params[:real_estate][:some_string_1]
        @estate.some_string_2 = params[:real_estate][:some_string_2]
        @estate.some_string_3 = params[:real_estate][:some_string_3]
        @estate.property_category = params[:real_estate][:property_category]
        @estate.some_string_4 = params[:real_estate][:some_string_4]
        @estate.price = params[:real_estate][:price]
        @estate.some_string_5 = params[:real_estate][:some_string_5]
        @estate.active = params[:real_estate][:active]
        @estate.some_timestamp_1 = params[:real_estate][:some_timestamp_1]
        @estate.some_timestamp_2 = params[:real_estate][:some_timestamp_2]
        @estate.some_count = params[:real_estate][:some_count]
        @estate.surface = params[:real_estate][:surface]
        @estate.some_boolean_1 = params[:real_estate][:some_boolean_1]
        @estate.some_boolean_2 = params[:real_estate][:some_boolean_2]
        res = @estate.save
        render json: { result: 'done', debug: { res_save_ar: res, changed: @estate.saved_changes?, \
          changes: @estate.saved_changes, previous_changes: @estate.previous_changes } }, status: 200
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: { errors: validation_result.errors.map{|key, error| "#{key} : #{error[0]}"} },  \
            status: :unprocessable_entity, serializer: nil }
        end
      end
    end

    def edit; end

    private 

    def set_form
      @estate = RealEstate.find(params[:id])
    end

    def real_estate_listing_params
      params[:real_estate_listing].permit(...) # all strong params edited in route, it's correct
    end
  end
end

AdminRealEstateSchema = Dry::Validation.Form do
  configure { config.type_specs = true, config.messages = :i18n }
  PROPERTY_CATEGORIES = %w(house apartment other)
  required(:property_category, :string).filled(:str?, included_in?: PROPERTY_CATEGORIES)
  required(:some_string_1, :string).filled(:str?)
  required(:some_string_2, :string).filled
  optional(:some_string_3).maybe(:str?)
  optional(:some_string_4).maybe(:str?)
  optional(:some_string_4).maybe(:str?)
  optional(:some_string_5).maybe(:str?)
  required(:price, :int).filled(:int?)
  optional(:some_other_int).maybe(:int?)
  optional(:some_count).maybe(:int?)
  required(:active, :bool).filled(:bool?)
  required(:some_boolean_1, :bool).filled(:bool?)
  required(:some_boolean_2, :bool).filled(:bool?)
  required(:some_time_1, :date_time).filled(:date_time?)
  optional(:some_time_2).maybe(:date_time?)
end
```

The view is correct, and using `remote: true`.

Now about the problem: **sometimes, but without consistency, the record is saved and updated thanks to the form, sometimes absolutely not**, like the changes have been rollbacked, even though `save` returns true, as can be seen in the returned JSON in the web console.

ActiveRecord also correctly and map all columns that should be updated/saved with correct values, as seen by `@estate.saved_changes`

Rspec tests all pass. But only in production, we encounter this error.

Now a few things to note that may be in importance:

- We already encountered a `create_or_find_by` bug a few months ago. Impossible to create records correctly. Rushed by deadlines, I resorted to raw SQL through `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` and it works.
- This table is very active with a lot of background jobs inserting/reading data from customers.
- There are no custom postgres triggers on this table.

I'm getting desperate and think it might be a bug in our code (obviously) or a bug in `activerecord`.

Any ideas or thoughts ?

Comment: I believe this may be related to a known bug in the latest stable releases. I would check [this open issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38265) along with some of the other open pg related issues. I ran into something similar when working with pg data types that weren't rails default int and string values (with JSONB and Money).

Comment: thank you @StevenFoster for your feedback. We are not in the case of the open issue (migrations are always run before code deploy on our end). I will look into other pg-related issues.

Comment: I believe in the reported issue, the migration is irrelevant. The behavior being certain data types in ActiveRecord are silently failing to commit to PostgreSQL regardless of time after migration. I have been able to isolate the issue to not occur with tables that use int, string, text, and the datetime types usually found in rails. but I've been able to reproduce with bigint, money, jsonb. And in the current stables intermittently see it with array. If I can find the bug in ActiveRecord, I'll submit a pull and update you here.

Comment: would you be able to update your question with the version of Postgres and the pg gem you are using? And if you can, isolate update issues to certain data types. e.g. In my triage-app I can update a table with strings and ints but if I add a money, jsonb, or bigint column and attempt to update that, I get the silent update failure.

Comment: I attempted to see if I could get something reproducible in the current stable branches but I am unable to reproduce the silent commit failures in Rails 6.0.2.1, Ruby 2.6.5, PostgreSQL 12, and pg 1.2.2 when saving JSONB, arrays, or money data types... My Rails 5.2.4.1 app that I saw this in doesn't seem to do it when the pg gem is 1.2.2. but given the intermittent nature of it at 1.1.4 I don't have a lot of confidence in the pg gem update resolving it. Still may be worth a shot.